# BigQuery select row_number() over (order by tablename) from dbc.tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, translation, teradata, row-number

I am translating a very large CTE Teradata query and got stuck at this following portion that is its own subquery, which is being cross joined into a much large subquery.

How can I translate this query into Bigquery?

```
(select row_number() over (order by tablename) subsequent_month from dbc.tables qualify row_number() over (order by tablename) <= 24)
```

Thoughts guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT subsequent_month FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tablename) subsequent_month 
  FROM dbc.tables 
) WHERE subsequent_month <= 24
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery for the `qualify`:

```
from (select row_number() over (order by tablename) as subsequent_month
      from dbc.tables
     ) t
where subsequent_month < 24;
```

In Teradata, `qualify` is a "where" clause that works on window functions.  It is analogous to `having` which works on aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

This simply returns 24 rows with consecutive numbers from 1 to 24.

So translate it to a similar query against a any table in BigQuery or use an existing *numbers* table.

Comment: Thanks!  I just wasn't sure about the dbc.table meta data but that clears it up that I can use any table.